# How can I change my local time?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use c# with webdriver and I need to run FirefoxDriver (or ChromeDriver), that js on website (for example https://whoer.net/) can't detect my real local time. So I need to send, that my local time is , for example, 05:30. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to get the local time? How about   `DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;` ?

Comment: no, if my local time == 12:58, How can i say whoer.net (or another website), that my local time == 05:30 ?

Comment: So you want to fake whoer into seeing a local time that's different from the real local time?

Comment: For example: My proxy - US , but my real IP - RU, so my local time - Ru, Moscow, but i want to change my local time to US, NY, for example. So i want that whoer.net detect my fake local time (US, NY)

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to use another time zone for the conversion, you have to do it manually... Store the time zone somewhere and use it for each conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can change local time by simply changing time zone and time, JS won't be able to take the correct time, but https://whoer.net/ uses your IP address too, they where the incoming call comes and put that region time. Also check your timezone

Comment: but how can I change my time zone in Webdriver c#? So I need to open via FirefoxDriver whoer.net and see, that Local timezone - not my real timezone)

Comment: doesn't it take your computer time?